# Authentication through iOS Settings

Tags: ios

How to add an entry in to the iPhone system settings to add custom service authentication? 
How to link it with the My Application?

I am looking something similar to Facebook and Twitter options available in the System settings for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Those are specifically built into iOS as part of the [Accounts framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/).

Answer (score 1):

I think the set of authentication providers is limited to the contents of `ACAccountTypes.h`:

```
ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter
ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook
ACAccountTypeIdentifierSinaWeibo
ACAccountTypeIdentifierTencentWeibo
ACAccountTypeIdentifierLinkedIn
```